# How to activate a datepicker calendar with a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a Matt Kruse datepicker, with three text inputs: date, month and year.  I am trying to get the calendar to open when someone clicks the date text input using the following Matt Kruse code:

```js
// Easy method to link the popup calendar with an input box:
cal.select(inputObject, anchorname, dateFormat);
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="cal.select(document.forms[0].date,'anchorname','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;"><input type="text" class="w2em" id="demo-3-dd" name="selStartDay" value="" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD"/></a>
```

But I am getting the following error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: inputObject is not defined

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Where does inputObject get defined?

Comment: I think that is my problem! I can't see any reference to it in the script.

Comment: OK, so either you need to define it or substitute it with a reference to the text box.  Try it out and that should fix that error.

Comment: Thanks - I am struggling to find the correct way to define it, any tips would be great!

Comment: For that I would need to see more code.  For cal.select, what are you doing?  Can you share more of your JS code, as well as any HTML, that would be relevant to this?

Comment: The only code I have is here: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/combined_source.html which has no other reference to cal.select, not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

I think the pages you're referencing are confusing with all of that text and it's making things seem over-complicated for what you're trying to do.  If you go [here](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/simple.html) and view the source, you will see a simple version of the calendar at work.

In other words, cal.select(inputObject, anchorname, dateFormat); is just the code that launches the calendar.  The variable inputObject would need to be defined somewhere, like so:

```
var inputObject = document.forms['example'].date1;
```

Let me know if this makes sense or not.